Screen freezes (nvidia_drm Flip event timeout on head 0), RTX 4060 Mobile
My screen randomly freezes, and this is accompanied with 2 lines of nvidia dmesg output after each freeze. The flip event timeouts are 3 seconds apart.
[ 2327.397254] [drm:nv_drm_atomic_commit [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Flip event timeout on head 0
[ 2330.469183] [drm:nv_drm_atomic_commit [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Flip event timeout on head 0
[ 3112.099516] [drm:nv_drm_atomic_commit [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Flip event timeout on head 0
[ 3115.171488] [drm:nv_drm_atomic_commit [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Flip event timeout on head 0
[ 4028.934165] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[ 4028.951027] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[ 4081.064294] [drm:nv_drm_atomic_commit [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Flip event timeout on head 0
[ 4084.135419] [drm:nv_drm_atomic_commit [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Flip event timeout on head 0
[ 4185.955776] [drm:nv_drm_atomic_commit [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Flip event timeout on head 0
[ 4188.963283] [drm:nv_drm_atomic_commit [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Flip event timeout on head 0

Troubleshooting Attempts:
Happens with both X11 and Wayland.
Happens on both Ubuntu 23.10 and 24.04 after clean installation
Happens across multiple NVIDIA driver versions 535, 545, 550, and 555.
Sometimes switching virtual terminals unfreezes the screen and other times it doesn't.
